# Combination problems

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, problem-solving

During numerous math contests I have come across questions such as: I have __ shirts, __ shoes and ___ pants... How many combinations of the __ are possible...

As well as many other combination related questions. I usually attempt these questions by listing all the combinations however, I have found this highly time consuming. So, I was wondering there is a more efficient method or formula that is used to solve such questions.

Help would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: In this example you multiply the number of shirts (6) , number of pairs of shoes (2) and the number of pants (4). Here there are $6 \cdot 2 \cdot 4=48$ combinations possible.

Comment: Oh is that it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, that´s it. You can proof it by counting. Maybe with smaller numbers.

Comment: See this Wikipedia article on the [Multiplication Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).